# Divs reaching side of page

Tags: html, css

I want to build a page that has an image at the top that reaches the side of the page. Like this link

http://www.workoutmeals.com.au/menu

Every time I try I have a gap at the edges. How do I make a div background reach the side of the page while having another background image in the body.

My Attempt

```
<body>
    <div id='banner'>
        Test
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body
{
background: url(../images/background.jpg);
margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#banner
{
background: url(../images/top_bg.jpg) no-repeat;
margin:0, padding:0;
    width: 100%;
height: 661px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS reset it wrong. You have a comma between margin:0 and padding:0, which should be a semicolon:

```
/*margin:0, padding:0;*/
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

If you fix that, it will work as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/y36cE/

Advice: don't put two style definitions on the same line, even for small ones like this. It makes your CSS less readable, and it's easier to overlook a small error like this.

Comment: I fixed that but still nothing. I still have a gap between the edge and the div

Comment: Nevermind, it's fixed. I didn't realise it was in body too lol

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify it, but you indeed made the same error twice.